# Does iOS 8 support AES in GCM mode to encrypt data in TLS/SSL?

Tags: ssl

While sending data over SSL/TLS in iOS 8 iPhone, is it possible to encrypt data using AES in GCM mode?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

YMMV depending on which app you're using or which SSL/TLS library you're using, if you're talking about your own app.

Comment: is there any method to determine which ssl/tls library an app uses or any other method to find out the encryption type

Comment: You could use packet sniffing such as Wireshark to determine which encryption type is being used. You can examine the app binary itself to try to detect the TLS library being used.